# Making [status] declined

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

The condition of [status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status) is declining rapidly.

- 1013 questions
- No excerpt
- No wiki

It's a very broad term that refers to no specific software or methodology, and is being combined with virtually every other tag on the site. The tag [status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/status) adds no value, and no one is an expert in "status". All of the questions I looked at that have the tag could easily survive without it.

Needless to say, status is in a bad state.

According to [Does this tag even need to be burninated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? **No**
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? **No**
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? **No**
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? **No**

Comment: You be an expert on meta in [status-declined](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-declined/topusers) ...

Comment: @rene http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/117/

Comment: Grrr https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-declined/topusers